# node supervisor incredibly slow on vagrant box - tips on how to debug?

Tags: macos, node.js, vagrant

I'm running a vagrant box with a Node app on it, on OSX. My problem is that running either `grunt` or `supervisor` to start the app is incredibly slow: it takes around 60 seconds to start the app, and 60 seconds to reload after a change.

I don't think the problem is in the app itself, since others are able to run it in the same Vagrant boxes on other machines without any problems.

Also, I'm also able to run other Vagrant boxes on this machine without any problems.

I've increased the memory available to the Vagrant box on the machine with no success.

Can anyone suggest how I could go about debugging this?

UPDATE: Running `top` on the Vagrant box *while grunt is also running* suggests that the Vagrant process is taking up 98% of the available CPU. Running `top` while grunt is not running shows that Vagrant is only taking up 3% of the available CPU. I'm not sure where to go from there. All suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the guest additions on the box are up-to-date ([vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) plugin can help). Especially if you're running the app from a synced folder.

And if you indeed use synced folder, using NFS can give a lot of speedup (see [this blog](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines)). Vagrant 1.5 will offer rsync synced folder, but until then you could also copy the app code to native VM disk if the performance is still an issue.